# How is the PyTorch Tensor source code organized?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am going to see if it's possible to port PyTorch to TypeScript, but not sure how the PyTorch repo is organized. It appears a lot of it is CUDA/C++, and I don't seem to find a [tensor.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/find/master) anywhere. Where is the source code the [Torch.Tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tensor.html) docs reference? That is, where is the tensor source code? If it is scattered across multiple files, could you point out the key ones?

For example, the [`tensor.sum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.sum.html#torch.Tensor.sum) function is nowhere to be found in the repo, as part of some "tensor" class in python. So now I assume it is a dynamically generated C/C++ binding or something, maybe even GLSL.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/_tensor.py?

Comment: I look in that file for some methods, like `add` or `sum` but don't find it, so I think it is somewhere else?